# downloading JSON from variable downloaded by JSON

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I need to download JSON files from my server.
once that is downloaded i need to run a second URL and download the files from there.
All this needs to happen BEFORE the user see's anything (apart from the loading dialog).

What i want is Download JSON from url and get the last name (lname), and get the first name (fname).
Then i need to construct an url like : http://google.nl/?user=lname&user2=fname. 
i then need to run that url, get all details from it and show it in my listView (i know how to do this).
Only question is how can i achieve that?
My thought was to put a call to a new method in the onPostExecute to call another class that does an AsyncTask but this didn't work out...

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                JSONObject first = contacts.getJSONObject(1);
                String lastname = first.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                String firstname = first.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);

                if(lastname != null){
                    url1 = "http://project-hr.nl/serviceview.php?&email="+lastname+"&pass="+firstname;
                    ServiceHandler sh1 = new ServiceHandler();
                    String jsonStrShare = sh1.makeServiceCall(url1, ServiceHandler.GET);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(jsonStrShare);
                        contacts1 = jsonObj1.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String lastsharename = c.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String list = c.getString(TAG_LIST);
                    String tussenv = c.getString(TAG_TUSSENV);
                    String pass = c.getString(TAG_PASS);
                    String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONENUMBER);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_LASTNAME, lastsharename);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_LIST, list);
                    contact.put(TAG_TUSSENV, tussenv);
                    contact.put(TAG_PASS, pass);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONENUMBER, phone);
                    //contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
        }
```

Comment: Just chain both requests in `doInBackground()` or use Volley. Your method should work too... what problems did you run into?

Comment: i have tried your answer however i think im missing something.. i've edited my question with the code. could you take a look? im getting " insert Finally statement to end try block"

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem. This is the code used to download JSON and download JSON again using the first JSON's parameters.

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (!jsonStr.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                JSONObject first = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
                Log.d("response lastname ", first.getString("lname"));
                Log.d("response firstname ", first.getString("fname"));
                String lastname = first.getString("lname");
                String firstname = first.getString("fname");
                Log.i("check if empty", ""+lastname);
                if(!lastname.isEmpty()){
                    url1 = "SPECIFY URL";//Put URL there
                    ServiceHandler sh1 = new ServiceHandler();
                    String jsonStrShare = sh1.makeServiceCall(url1, ServiceHandler.GET);
                        JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(jsonStrShare);
                        contacts1 = jsonObj1.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts1.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts1.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String lastsharename = c.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String list = c.getString(TAG_LIST);
                    String tussenv = c.getString(TAG_TUSSENV);
                    String pass = c.getString(TAG_PASS);
                    String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONENUMBER);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_LASTNAME, lastsharename);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_LIST, list);
                    contact.put(TAG_TUSSENV, tussenv);
                    contact.put(TAG_PASS, pass);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONENUMBER, phone);
                    //contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);

                }
                }   
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
```